# How can I input a string in ZX Spectrum BASIC using INPUT and not show the quotation marks?

Tags: zx-spectrum, basic

How can I input a string in ZX Spectrum BASIC and not show the quotation marks on input?

I've written a program for my 3-year old daughter to type in some letters, but she keeps deleting the quotations marks by accident and then gets stuck when the Spectrum shows a flashing `?` :-)

Comment: Teaching her right! Can you share the program? Am curious... had my 3 yr old playing Putt Putt recently :)

Comment: I can do, it's very simple - just inputs a string, changes the colour each time, then prints it to the screen. She really enjoys just typing letters and watching them change colour...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
INPUT LINE a$
```

See [the ZX Spectrum Basic manual](http://www.worldofspectrum.org/ZXBasicManual/zxmanchap15.html).

Note that plain `INPUT a$` will accept quite arbitrary string expressions, e.g. entering `"a"+"b"` is the same as entering `"ab"`, and you can even use other (defined) string variables. The quotes are thus nothing more than a part of the string expression.

Comment: Thanks so much! I forgot what the syntax was (I knew I'd done it years ago, but couldn't remember how).